# When does tabularx decide to break the cell entry instead of reducing the columns separation?

Tags: tables, tabularx

For the following, why did tabularx decide to break the second column cell entry instead of reducing the separation of the columns?

Additionally, how can I make `\rowstyle{\bfseries}` work to bold any cell content whether it is text or math?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,mathtools,siunitx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{b}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.5\hsize$}X<{$}}
    \newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{m}{>{\RaggedLeft\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
    \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}bm*{8}{%
                S[table-format=2.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places,
                round-integer-to-decimal=true]%
            }@{}}
        \toprule
        \rowstyle{\bfseries}
        & $\delta$ [deg] & \heading{5} & \heading{10} & \heading{15} & \heading{20} & \heading{25} & \heading{30} & \heading{35} & \heading{40} \\
        \midrule
        \Gamma = x^2 & $\beta$ [deg] & 1 & 1 & 1 & 18 & 21 & 46 & 72 & 63 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tabularx` is completely unsuitable for numeric data tables  really.

To answer your question it is important to realize that `tabularx` never adjusts inter-column space (`tabular*` does that) and never looks at the content of any cell in the table. It simply makes each `X` column into a `p{...}` column, choosing the value to use for `...` so the table ends up at the specified total width. As such the only thing `tabularx` controls is the target width for *line breaking* within a cell, and in a table of numeric values there is no line breaking.

If you want adjustment of inter-columns space, and no line breaking then `tabular*` is what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,mathtools,siunitx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{b}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.5\hsize$}X<{$}}
    \newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{m}{>{\RaggedLeft\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
    \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
@{\extracolsep{0pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}}
>{$}l<{$}
l
*{8}{%
                S[table-format=2.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places,
                round-integer-to-decimal=true]%
            }@{}}
        \toprule
        & $\delta$ [deg] & \heading{5} & \heading{10} & \heading{15} & \heading{20} & \heading{25} & \heading{30} & \heading{35} & \heading{40} \\
        \midrule
        \Gamma = x^2 & $\beta$ [deg] & 1 & 1 & 1 & 18 & 21 & 46 & 72 & 63 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I would be grateful if you could help me understand what `@{\extracolsep{0pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}}` means. Additionally, could you please give me a hint of why `\rowstyle` fails in my code?

Comment: @Diaa tabular* meets the target width by adding the `\extracolsep` space between columns, normally you can just use `\fill` but here the table is too wide so actually you want to add negative space. there I added a space with natural width 0pt that can stretch to 5pt or shrink to -3pt which allows the table to be squeezed up a bit and fit.

Comment: After some experimenting, I found that `@{\extracolsep{0pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}}` only affects locally the inter-column spacing based on where I typed it among the columns alignment parameter. If what I found is true, is it possible to make this command affect globally all the columns without having to type manually?

Comment: @Diaa sorry i don't understand that comment. `\extracolsep` affects all columns from the point it is set within that table.

Comment: Is it possible to have `tabularx` with different column separations? For example, in [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521363/2288), I need to globally set the separation to be `0ex` while injecting some space of `2ex` between the first and the second columns; is this possible?

Comment: @Diaa you can set `\extracolsep` as many times as you link between any columns, also add additional space with `@\hspace{2cm}` or several other possibilities (basically all the features of a standard `tabular*` are available in `tabularx`)

Comment: There is a problem with colored rows when using `@\hspace{5ex}` between the first two columns, [this document](https://pastebin.com/BqPGcXJi) has [this ugly output](https://i.ibb.co/qgHhQDN/image.png).

Comment: the tabularx document shows how to use the overhang arguments to span across `@`

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but I went through the manual, and my lack of enough knowledge didn't help me know how to do it. So, I would be grateful if you could refer me to a question addressing the usage of `@{\hspace{}}` and/or `\extracolsep{}` for tabularx while preserving the colored rows.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `tabular*` like David, but in a different way.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

% initialization for this table
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\boldmath#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX compute
\sisetup{
  table-format=2.2,
  round-precision=2,
  round-mode=places,
  round-integer-to-decimal=true,
}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{2}{l} *{8}{S} }
\toprule
& \heading{$\delta$ [deg]}
& \heading{5} & \heading{10} & \heading{15} & \heading{20}
& \heading{25} & \heading{30} & \heading{35} & \heading{40} \\
\midrule
$\Gamma = x^2$ & $\beta$ [deg] & 1 & 1 & 1 & 18 & 21 & 46 & 72 & 63 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes well that's probably what I'd do too, or more likely just use `tabular` and set `tabcolsep` to the right value calculated from an overfull box message, but I wanted to demonstrate the shrink possibility as there are not many examples of that on site (or anywhere)

Comment: Thanks for showing this approach. Could you please explain the difference in interpretation between ‘\tabular*{\linewidth}’ and ’\tabular*{\columnwidth}’?

Comment: @Diaa `\linewidth` stores the length of lines in list environments. It *may* coincide with `\columnwidth`. It mostly depends on where you want to set your table. If in a `table*` environment in a two-column document, `\textwidth` should be used instead.